# What exactly is our goal of using ORM in context of application layer?

Tags: database, orm

Is the goal of an ORM to hide persistence from the application layer? Or is it to insulate the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of benefits to using an ORM, but the most basic one is that it helps address the [impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch) between relational databases and object-oriented code. For me, it is a huge productivity boost. It is a pain to manually write boilerplate code that accesses the database and iterates over the result set to populate your objects.

There are other benefits too like optimized queries (in a good ORM), caching, and so on achieved with configuration rather than having to deal with it myself.

Encapsulating the data access code certainly happens, but that could also be accomplished with a design pattern like Factory or Facade.

This is a big, popular topic, so you will find a lot of resources to help you decide what you should do.

Hope that helps.